# How can I access data from child component without emiting it

Tags: angular, components, share

[image]So like the picture discribes, The parent component is in blue and the red is the child component, so I want to type in some data in the input which is in the child component and when I click on the add answer button, i want to get the value from the input sent to the parent component.
can anyone help me with that ?

I tried onchange event listener on the input so I can emit the value but it didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs

Event emitters are a fundamental Angular concept. The child has an EventEmitter which the parent listens to. To trigger an event on a button click in the child, your code should look similar to the following:

```
<!-- parent template -->
<my-child (myEvent)="handleMyEvent($event)"></my-child>
```

```
// child component
@Component({...}))
export class MyChildComponent {
  
  @Output() myEvent = new EventEmitter<SomeType>()
  
  handleButtonClicked() {
    this.myEvent.emit(someValue)
  }
```

```
<!--child template-->
<button (click)="handleButtonClicked()>Some button</button>
```

UPDATE:

In this case, you'll need to store the contents of the input on the parent component, or access them at the time of add.

your child component could have a listener on the input that emits the value of the input:

```
<!-- child template -->
<input (change)="emitChange($event)" type="text" />
```

```
// child component
@Output() myEvent = newEventEmitter<string>()
emitChange(event: string) {
  this.myEvent.emit(event)
}
```

Your parent component's handleMyEvent function would need to manage storing the values emitted from the child component(s).

Comment: the add button is in the parent component thats the issue

Comment: I've updated my answer accordingly.